# Minimax problem for optimization $\inf \sup \frac{x f(x)}{\int_0^1 f(t) dt}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Consider $\bar{C} = C_{d}^0[0,1] $ is the space of continuous decreasing functions, s.a. $f(1) = 0$. We want to determine $\displaystyle \inf_{f \in \bar{C}} \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \frac{x f(x)}{\int_0^1 f(t) dt}$.

I thought about $\displaystyle xf(x) = xf(x) + 1\cdot f(1) = \int^x_1 f(t)dt - \int_1^x tf'(t)dt$. Actually I even don't know whether derivate exists or not. 
Now we should consider $\dfrac{\int^1_x \left[tf'(t) + f(t)\right] dt}{\int_0^1 f(t)}$. 
Then I thought about Poincare inequality, but fails there. Any hints ?

Comment: do you need the function to be analytic?

Comment: @geocalc33 don't think so. It would give us a lot of opportunities.

Comment: I think the expression in the integral should be $-tf'(t)-f(t)$ since you are using that $(xf(x))'=xf'(x)+f(x)$

Comment: Also, I believe the derivative is fine if your integrals are in the Lebesgue sense because a monotone functions is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: @user293794 you're right.

Comment: What if you try $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{x}$? Then $xf(x)$ is bounded, but the integral diverges, so you can make the supremum as small to zero as you want by fixing $f$ around zero, for example, by saturating $f(x)=n$ on $[0,1/n]$.

Comment: This isn't continuous on the closed interval.

Comment: Actually, it should be $f(x)=n-1$ because of the shift one unit down.

Comment: @A.Γ. but this function isn't continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Take $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n-1,\  x\in[0,1/n]\\ \frac{1-x}{x},\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ Then let $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $f_n(x) = \min(n,{1 \over x}, {n^2\over n-1}(1-x))$.

Note that $f_n(x) = n$ for $x \in [0,{1 \over n}]$, $f_n(x) = {1 \over x}$ for $x \in [{ 1\over n}, 1-{1 \over n}]$ and the graph of $f_n$ is a straight line joining the points $(1-{1 \over n}, {1 \over 1-{1 \over n}}), (1,0)$ for $x \in [{1-{1 \over n}},1]$.

Note that $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} x f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$.
We have $\int_0^1 f_n(t) dt = 1+ \log(n-1)+ {1 \over 2(n-1)}$.

Hence $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} { x f_n(x) \over \int_0^1 f_n(t) dt} = { 1\over 1+ \log(n-1)+ {1 \over 2(n-1)}}$ and letting $n \to \infty$ we see that the
$\inf$ over $\bar{C}$ is zero.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Would $f = \lim f_n$ be in the same class?

Comment: And more general problem is $f_n$ isn't decreasing function. I guess your solution works for non-increasing functions.

Comment: The limiting function is not bounded, so no. If $x \le y$ then $f_n(x) \ge f_n(y)$, so it is decreasing.

Comment: In any event, it is straightforward to modify $f_n$ so that it is strictly decreasing on the first interval, if that it what you meant?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure whether $f_n$ should be decreasing or *strictly* decreasing. So anyway we may update $f$ to be strictly decreasing.

Comment: It doesn't matter as I said. For example, replace the first $n$ in the $\min$ above by $n+{1 \over n} ({1 \over n} -x)$ if you want a strictly decreasing function. The integral value needs to be modified slightly but every thing else remains the same.

Comment: Yes, I understand. You're right.Thanks!