# How to find $\underset{f \in M}{inf} \underset{x \in [0,1]}{sup} \frac{x f(x)}{\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(t)dt} $?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose, that M is a set of decreasing functions on a segment [0,1], such that $f(1) = 0$ and I need to find:

$$\underset{f \in M}{inf} \underset{x \in [0,1]}{sup} \frac{x f(x)}{\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(t)dt} $$

I guess, that answer is 0, but I don't know how to prove it. This is my reasoning:

1) let's notice that $xf(x) \geqslant 0, x\in [0,1]$

2) and $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(t)dt \geqslant 0$, because $F(1) - F(0) > 0$

3) than $\frac{x f(x)}{\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(t)dt} \geqslant 0$

After this step, am I right that I must find a sequence of functions $\{f\}_i$ that $\underset{i \rightarrow \infty}{lim}$ $\underset{x \in [0,1]}{max} f_i = 0$ to prove the statement?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654075/minimax-problem-for-optimization-inf-sup-fracx-fx-int-01-ft-dt?noredirect=1#comment7509355_3654075

Comment: Where is this question from by the way?

Comment: @user293794, Thank you!